# juju override defaults in service

Tags: juju, postgresql

Working on the postgresql charm a bit, and I'm wondering if there is a way to supply overrides for default values in a "juju-way".

In my charm that will be consuming the services provided by postgresql, I was thinking I could override things like the database name, or the name of the super_user created.  If I stick something like this in the relation-joined:

```
relation-set user=my_superuser
```

I'm having an issue where the postgres/db-admin-relation-changed can actually run before the consumer joins runs (or finishes running at least).

Eventually, the postgresql/db-admin-relation-changed will run and get my data, but if it runs too quickly, I could wind up with 2 superusers.

TL;DR:  Is there a way to guarantee that default configuration is overridden in a service on the provides side of the relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee which hook runs first in the hook execution scheme, but you can predict which hook series will execute first. When a relation is added the `*-relation-joined` hooks are fired first (on both services, with no clear winner of who goes first), followed by the `*-relation-changed` hooks for each service. Since you can't guarantee which of the who hooks in a given relation state will fire first you can trump the `relation-changed` hook on the Postgres charm by placing your relation-set commands in `relation-joined` hook in your charm.

This won't work for every charm/relation as it depends on where the heavy lifting is done for each relation. For example, the MySQL charm does all the database creation instructions during the `relation-joined` hook, so the above wouldn't actually help you achieve anything as you'd still have the race condition.

Ideally unless there's a *really* good reason using what the postgres charm provides is probably the best way to go.